# connecting to WMI Server fails c++ windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wmi

I'm trying to get the motherboard DeviceId on Windows 10.

This was working previosly (last week) but it stopped now and I'm not sure why.

The code I have is the same as this basically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-iwbemlocator-connectserver

The problem is that the last verification if(FAILED(hres)) is true (meaning the connection failed, which hadn't happened before, it started today, and I am not sure why. The only thing that changed in the project is that I added plog (https://github.com/SergiusTheBest/plog) which should not change anything related to WMI

I also turned on windows security does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Check the value of hres.  Here is the list of errors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants

Comment: Which (error) code is returned by ConnectServer() ?  And regaring your last sentence, yes that's likely the reason. Turn off windows security again to see if it works again.

Comment: when I did: std::system_category().message(hres) i got: An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call.

Comment: the actual result is 8001010D which is none of the values expected

Comment: got it, I had set the mode to COINIT_APPARTMENTTHREAD on CoInitializeEx but was calling the method on a different thread